# Транзакции mysql на разных шардах

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Есть таблицы InnoDB со счетами пользователей, находятся на разных шардах. Стоит задача: сделать аналог транзакции для перевода с одного счета на другой. Как делаю я:
 1. Один счет уменьшаю
 2. Затем увеличиваю другой
 3. Сравниваю их после изменения. Если не сходится - откатываю обратно.

При такой схеме на моем сайте вероятна ситуация "гонки", если между обращениями к БД другой запрос изменит счет одного из пользователей.

Как этого избежать? Держать все счета на одном сервере в одной БД и использовать встроенный механизм транзакций? Но такая схема плохо масштабируема в отличие от шардирования.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону [**блокировок**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) (**table lock** и **record lock**) записей в InnoDB. [Вот тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150075/) есть небольшая шапаргалка.

Схема работы видится такая:

1. Уменьшение первого счёта, установка блокировки на эту запись.
2. Увеличение второго счёта, установка блокировки на эту запись.
3. Сравнение транзакции.
4. Снятие блокировок.

Это, возможно, уменьшит скорость выполнения программы, но такова плата за синхронизацию.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю тут будет правильно не манипулировать уменьшением/увеличеванием, а создать таблицу транзакций - в одной записи отрицательная сумма на номер счёта, в другой такая же положительная, ну и связать их наверное ещё.

А остаток по счёту, рассчитывать суммой по транзакциям

Comment: +1 Наверняка задним числом кто-то да поинтересуется историей транзакций.